# Logic Apps Outlook Get Events - Issue With Recurring Events

Tags: outlook, azure-logic-apps, connector

[image]I have a Logic App that I need to get events from a Calendar in Outlook. I am specify the dates I am interested in like this.

Start/DateTime ge '2023-07-01' and End/DateTime le '2023-07-31'

Problem is that recurring events that where started outside of this time period aren't returned even though an instance of the event occurs during the defined time period.

Anyone know how to get these recurring events included?

Comment: can you please share the flow diagram?

Comment: I add the screenshot to the original questions as I could see now way of adding it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps Outlook Get Events - Issue With Recurring Events

Get Events(v4) connector, gives output those events whose starting date is in between the provided start date and end date.

**For Example:** I have created a meeting in teams starting from 26th July 2023 and ending on 29th July 2023.
[image]
[image]

***Note:-** I have used UTC time zone. Please use as per your requirement time zone*
**Input: -**
**Start date 25th July 2023 end date 30th July 2023**
[image]
**Output:-**
it gives output of only single instance of the recurring event.
[image]

To get all the recurrence event in specified date Please use “**Get calendar views of event(V3)**”
**Input:-**

[image]

**Output:-** It will give output of all the recurrence in the specified date
[image]

[image]